# Errors importing JSON file to MySQL using mysqlsh Util.import_json

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, json, apparmor

I am having errors in attempting to import a file into MySQL (8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2) using:

```
mysqlsh mysqluser@localhost/jsondb --import /path/to/file.json
```

If the file is in, say, my home directory, regardless of what I do,

```
mysqlsh mysqluser@localhost/jsondb --import /home/myuser/file.json
```

I get:

```
Importing from file "/home/myuser/file.json" to collection `jsondb`.`file` in MySQL Server at localhost:33060

Processed 0 bytes in 0 documents in 0.0014 sec (0.00 documents/s)
Total successfully imported documents 0 (0.00 documents/s)
ERROR: Util.importJson: /home/myuser/file.json: Permission denied (error code 13)
```

Also in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Apr  8 09:10:43 hostname kernel: [ 8158.145542] audit: type=1400 audit(1680952123.439:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.mysql-shell.mysqlsh" name="/home/myuser/file.json" pid=3333 comm="mysqlsh" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=118
```

I have attempted disabling apparmor about any way I could, short of uninstalling it altogether: disabling it; installing `apparmor-utils` and running `aa-disable mysqld` (and restarting mysql).  I changed permission to `777`, gave ownership to `mysql:mysql`; the same result every time.

Now, if I copy the json file to `/tmp` or `/var/mysql` (even assigning ownership to `mysql:mysql` and giving `777` permissions) the error is:

```
ERROR: Util.importJson: Path "/tmp/file.json" does not exist.
```

Also, if I put the file in `/home/mysql/file.json` with `chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql`, I also get the "Access denied" error.

However, if I move it to `/mysql/file.json`(with `mysql:mysql` having ownership of `/mysql`, I get "Path does not exist."

It seems that if I put the file in a *path* that is not natively accessible to the `mysql` user all the way from `/`, Apparmor denies access to the file.  However, if it seems that MySQL will have rights to the file, it returns "Path does not exist."

I should also note that I had to use actual MySQL and not Mariadb, as I could see no way of installing `mysqlx` in Mariadb.  (Both were from the Ubuntu repository.)